# WSO2 BAM + shared registry

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to follow the following guide http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/2010/04/sharing-registry-space-across-multiple-product-instances to have a BAM pointing to a shared registry.

Versions of the two: BAM 2.2.0 greg 4.5.3
Platform CentOS 6.3
JAVA 1.6

Both point to the same MySQL server.

So the configuration is 3 VM:
1 BAM
1 GREG
1 MySQl

On greg

```
<datasource>
        <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://wso2mysql.prod.local:3306/odaigreg</url>
                <username>odaigreg</username>
                <password>odaigreg1</password>
                <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>80</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <minIdle>5</minIdle>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>
```

on BAM

```
   <datasource>
        <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://wso2mysql.prod.local:3306/odaibam</url>
                <username>odaibam</username>
                <password>odaibam1</password>
                <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>30</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <minIdle>5</minIdle>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>

    <datasource>
       <name>WSO2BAM_DATASOURCE</name>
       <description>The datasource used for analyzer data</description>
       <definition type="RDBMS">
           <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://wso2mysql.prod.local:3306/odaibam</url>
                <username>odaibam</username>
                <password>odaibam1</password>
                <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>30</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <minIdle>5</minIdle>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
       </definition>
   </datasource>
```

and in the registry.xml

```
<currentDBConfig>wso2registry</currentDBConfig>
<readOnly>false</readOnly>
<enableCache>true</enableCache>
<registryRoot>/</registryRoot>

<dbConfig name="wso2registry">
    <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</dataSource>
</dbConfig>

 <dbConfig name="governanceRegistry">
     <url>jdbc:mysql://wso2mysql.prod.local:3306/odaigreg</url>
     <username>odaigreg</username>
     <password>odaigreg1</password>
     <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
     <maxActive>30</maxActive>
     <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
     <minIdle>5</minIdle>
     <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
     <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
     <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
</dbConfig>
<remoteInstance url="https://wso2greg.prod.local:9443/registry">
    <id>governanceRegistryInstance</id>
    <dbConfig>governanceRegistry</dbConfig>
    <readOnly>false</readOnly>
    <enableCache>true</enableCache>
    <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>

<mount path="/_system/governance" overwrite="true">
    <instanceId>governanceRegistryInstance</instanceId>
    <targetPath>/_system/governance</targetPath>
</mount>
```

I get this error:

```
    TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-04-30 16:26:01,052]  INFO {org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor} -  Loading settings from file:/opt/wso2bam-2.2.0/repository/conf/etc/cassandra.yaml {org.apache.
cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-04-30 16:26:01,146]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.bam.toolbox.deployer.internal.DataBridgeRecieverServiceComponent} -  Successfully setted data bridge reciever service {org.wso2.
carbon.bam.toolbox.deployer.internal.DataBridgeRecieverServiceComponent}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-04-30 16:26:01,153]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.DataBridgeDS} -  Successfully deployed Agent Server  {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.DataBrid
geDS}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-04-30 16:26:01,622]  INFO {org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor} -  DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap {org.apache.cassandra.co
nfig.DatabaseDescriptor}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-04-30 16:26:01,622]  INFO {org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor} -  DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap {org.apache.cassandra.co
nfig.DatabaseDescriptor}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-04-30 16:26:01,820]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Configured Registry in 222ms {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry
Service}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-04-30 16:26:01,939]  INFO {org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor} -  Global memtable threshold is enabled at 329MB {org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor
}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-04-30 16:26:01,939]  INFO {org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor} -  Global memtable threshold is enabled at 329MB {org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor
}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-04-30 16:26:01,993] FATAL {org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator} -  Failed to create database tables for registry resource store. null {org.wso2.carbon.utils.db
creator.DatabaseCreator}
java.sql.SQLException
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:253)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:694)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:626)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:182)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.createRegistryDatabase(DatabaseCreator.java:58)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCDataAccessManager.createDatabase(JDBCDataAccessManager.java:122)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.configure(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:189)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.<init>(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryContext.getEmbeddedRegistryService(RegistryContext.java:644)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.getRegistry(MountHandler.java:221)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.resourceExists(MountHandler.java:322)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.resourceExists(MountHandler.java:302)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.resourceExists(HandlerManager.java:3130)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.UserDefinedHandlerManager.resourceExists(UserDefinedHandlerManager.java:260)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.resourceExists(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:1293)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.resourceExists(EmbeddedRegistry.java:637)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.resourceExists(CacheBackedRegistry.java:250)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.resourceExists(UserRegistry.java:630)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryUtils.systemResourceShouldBeAdded(RegistryUtils.java:573)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryUtils.addServiceStoreCollection(RegistryUtils.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.buildRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:582)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.activate(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:120)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:252)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:588)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:328)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:68)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:245)
        ... 60 more
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-04-30 16:26:01,996] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Error occurred while creating the database {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.Em
beddedRegistryService}
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-04-30 16:26:01,996] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryContext} -  Couldn't initialize EmbeddedRegistryService. Error occurred while creating the database
 {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryContext}
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Error occurred while creating the database
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.configure(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:193)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.<init>(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryContext.getEmbeddedRegistryService(RegistryContext.java:644)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.getRegistry(MountHandler.java:221)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.resourceExists(MountHandler.java:322)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.resourceExists(MountHandler.java:302)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.resourceExists(HandlerManager.java:3130)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.UserDefinedHandlerManager.resourceExists(UserDefinedHandlerManager.java:260)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.resourceExists(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:1293)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.resourceExists(EmbeddedRegistry.java:637)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.resourceExists(CacheBackedRegistry.java:250)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.resourceExists(UserRegistry.java:630)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryUtils.systemResourceShouldBeAdded(RegistryUtils.java:573)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryUtils.addServiceStoreCollection(RegistryUtils.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.buildRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:582)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.activate(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:120)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:252)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:588)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:328)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:68)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Error in creating the database
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCDataAccessManager.createDatabase(JDBCDataAccessManager.java:125)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.configure(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:189)
        ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Failed to create database tables for registry resource store. null
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.createRegistryDatabase(DatabaseCreator.java:69)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCDataAccessManager.createDatabase(JDBCDataAccessManager.java:122)
        ... 53 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:253)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:694)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:626)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:182)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.createRegistryDatabase(DatabaseCreator.java:58)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:245)
        ... 60 more
TID: [0] [BAM] [2013-04-30 16:26:02,002] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.ResourceImpl} -  Unable to test existence of resource {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.ResourceImpl}
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Couldn't initialize EmbeddedRegistryService. Error occurred while creating the database
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryContext.getEmbeddedRegistryService(RegistryContext.java:648)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.getRegistry(MountHandler.java:221)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.resourceExists(MountHandler.java:322)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.builtin.MountHandler.resourceExists(MountHandler.java:302)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerManager.resourceExists(HandlerManager.java:3130)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.UserDefinedHandlerManager.resourceExists(UserDefinedHandlerManager.java:260)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.handlers.HandlerLifecycleManager.resourceExists(HandlerLifecycleManager.java:1293)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistry.resourceExists(EmbeddedRegistry.java:637)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.caching.CacheBackedRegistry.resourceExists(CacheBackedRegistry.java:250)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.session.UserRegistry.resourceExists(UserRegistry.java:630)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryUtils.systemResourceShouldBeAdded(RegistryUtils.java:573)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.utils.RegistryUtils.addServiceStoreCollection(RegistryUtils.java:848)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.buildRegistryService(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:582)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent.activate(RegistryCoreServiceComponent.java:120)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:252)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:346)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:588)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:328)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:68)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1130)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Error occurred while creating the database
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.configure(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:193)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.<init>(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.config.RegistryContext.getEmbeddedRegistryService(RegistryContext.java:644)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Error in creating the database
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCDataAccessManager.createDatabase(JDBCDataAccessManager.java:125)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService.configure(EmbeddedRegistryService.java:189)
        ... 52 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Failed to create database tables for registry resource store. null
        at org.wso2.carbon.utils.dbcreator.DatabaseCreator.createRegistryDatabase(DatabaseCreator.java:69)
        at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.dataaccess.JDBCDataAccessManager.createDatabase(JDBCDataAccessManager.java:122)
        ... 53 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:253)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:694)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:626)
        at
```

Any hints?
Thanks
Luca

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial has some obsolete configurations. You need to follow 
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/BAM220/Sharing+Registry+Space+Among+Multiple+Products

for updated documentation.

Can you remove following from registry.xml and do following changes on BAM.

```
<dbConfig name="governanceRegistry">
     <url>jdbc:mysql://wso2mysql.prod.local:3306/odaigreg</url>
     <username>odaigreg</username>
     <password>odaigreg1</password>
     <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
     <maxActive>30</maxActive>
     <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
     <minIdle>5</minIdle>
     <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
     <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
     <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
</dbConfig>
```

and also change dbconfig in.

```
<remoteInstance url="https://wso2greg.prod.local:9443/registry">
    <id>governanceRegistryInstance</id>
    <dbConfig>wso2registry</dbConfig>
    <readOnly>false</readOnly>
    <enableCache>true</enableCache>
    <registryRoot>/</registryRoot>
</remoteInstance>
```

If you have problems still.

Further you can use H2 database (or use another database) to store BAM's data without using all in one which is correct approach.

To do that quickly 
On BAM server please try to do following.

Keep exisiting H2 databsae for WSO2_CARBON_DB (master-datasources.xml)

```
<datasource>
            <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:h2:repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000</url>
                    <username>wso2carbon</username>
                    <password>wso2carbon</password>
                    <driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>
```

and rename dbconfig such that it will use WSO2BAM_DATASOURCE (registry.xml)

```
<dbConfig name="wso2registry">
    <dataSource>jdbc/WSO2BAM_DATASOURCE</dataSource>
</dbConfig>
```

Comment: The error is gone, but if I login in GREG and than login in BAM I find myself with expired session is this correct is it there something else that I have to set to fix this stuff.  It seems to be linked with the clustering problem, but both axix2.xml file have beein modified setting to true the <clustering class="org.apache.axis2.clustering.tribes.TribesClusteringAgent" enable="true">  Is it there any other stuff left behind?

Comment: Can you try accessing management console with two browsers ? You need to enable clustering if you enable registry caching and that clustering message will invalidate the cache when required. Usually logging out is not a problem but a minor usability issue.